# How to add custom action in sharepoint that visible only for specific group

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create custom action in c# code for sharepoint list.

I am using **SPUserCustomAction** type and i need to display this item only for specific users (user are presented in specific group)

Location set to "Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu";

How can I specify in code that only few users that belongs to my custom group can see this menu item? Any links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Rights` Attribute is your friend. Here you can set which rights are required for your custom action to be shown like so:

```
Rights = "ViewListItems"
```

The rights are based on the `SPBasePermission` enumeration which you can [find here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx).

Also see this blog post about [security trimming custom actions](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/10/15/security-trimmed-custom-actions.aspx).

Comment: I need to grand access for this menu item only for custom group "CustomSiteEditors" how can i do this? For other users menu item should be hidden.

Comment: Not possible to use groups. You can only use rights. You could give the group some special permission like `ApplyStyleSheets` which no other group has, but that will be all you can do. You could also limit the action to site administrators.

Comment: Your blog post link is broken, here is a link to [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edhild/2008/01/16/how-to-add-security-trimming-info-to-custom-actions-in-sharepoint/)